# Fetch with no-cors mode and check if file on given URL is found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, fetch-api

I am trying to check if **html** file on given URL exists. We have a FTP server and URL's look like this:

```
http://10.200.11.60/ftpfiles/ftpfiles/<file_name>.html
```

Locally, in React, I was trying to fetch this URL using HEAD method - just to check if this file exists:

```
const result = await fetch('http://10.200.11.60/ftpfiles/ftpfiles/<file_name>.html, {
  method: 'HEAD'
});
```

but I got a CORS error:

> Access to fetch at 'http://10.200.11.60/ftpfiles/ftpfiles/<file_name>.html' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

So I switched to **no-cors** mode in *fetch* configuration and now in network tab I can see the 404 and 200 responses, but in result of fetch action when console logging the response I get status=0 (as expected). How can i get this info here? Or is there any better way to check if file on given URL exists and I don't have an access to change CORS on FTP server?

Answer (score 1):

`fetch` with `{mode: "no-cors"}` gives you an *opaque* response that does not reveal its `status` (nor its `headers`, nor its `body`, ...). The purpose of `no-cors` is to just *make* the request, not look into its response.

CORS is meant to protect your browser from inadvertently making requests to your disadvantage. Imagine being lured to a malicious HTML page that requests in `no-cors` mode a file `job_application.html` from your FTP server and notifies your current employer if it finds that such a file exists (`status = 200`). Such an attack is prevented by the opacity of the response.

If you want to check the existence of a file on a server, you must make the call from your own *server*, not from the *browser*. CORS does not apply to server-to-server calls.